# thrust::max_element() returns incorrect values for a 2D matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, thrust

I try to use thrust to find the max element from a 2D matrix. However, I always get incorrent results. The codes work well for 1D matrix but behave unpredictably when using 2D matrix.

I use opencv GpuMat for 2D matrix. Here are my codes. I wonder if someone met the same problem?

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h> 
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <iostream> 

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\cuda.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

ushort thrust_find_max_idx(const GpuMat& in_, int* p_r_, int* p_c_){
    thrust::device_ptr<ushort> ptr((ushort*)in_.data);
    unsigned int N = in_.cols * in_.rows;
    thrust::device_vector<ushort>::iterator iter = thrust::max_element(ptr, ptr + N); //find max element
    int pos = thrust::device_pointer_cast(&(iter[0])) - ptr;
    *p_r_ = pos / in_.cols; 
    *p_c_ = pos % in_.cols;
    return *iter;
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    Mat cpu_matrix; cpu_matrix.create(10, 10, CV_16UC1);
    randu(cpu_matrix, 1, 256); //generate random sequences
    GpuMat matrix; matrix.upload(cpu_matrix);
    int r, c;
    ushort max = thrust_find_max_idx( matrix, &r, &c);
    matrix.download(cpu_matrix);    
    cout << cpu_matrix << endl; //output testing sequences
    cout << max << " r " << r << " c " << c << endl; //output max element and positions

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `GpuMat` is a [pitched allocation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/gtc-express-itseez-opencv-webinar.pdf) in the 2D case.  Your code doesn't seem to be accounting for that, instead it presumes that all the data are contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Robert's reply, I realize that [GpuMat](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/cuda/doc/data_structures.html) is not continuously allocated as Mat by default, but luckily, the Function [cuda::minMaxLoc()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/cudaarithm/doc/reductions.html?highlight=minmax#void%20cuda::minMaxLoc(InputArray%20src,%20double*%20minVal,%20double*%20maxVal,%20Point*%20minLoc,%20Point*%20maxLoc,%20InputArray%20mask)) can be used for quickly identifying max element in a GpuMat.

```
double max; cv::Point loc;
cv::cuda::minMaxLoc(matrix, 0, &max, 0, &loc);
```